# Como configurar Web API com múltiplos Get

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Preciso fornecer na minha web api três formas de consulta: Primeiro Get com todos os registros "GetAll", o segundo GET pelo id e um terceiro GET com opções de fitragem, enviados pelo cliente, ex.: Nome contém a letra "a" e endereço contém a palavra "ponte", pensei em enviar por queryString, mas não bate na action correta, exemplo incompleto de como pensei em fazer o Get de filtrados:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFiltrados() {
    string condicao = "";
    string[] filtros = Request.RequestUri.Query.Substring(1).Split('&');
    foreach (var filtro in filtros) {
        condicao += "";
    }
    if (reg != null) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, reg);
    } else {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Registro não encontrado");
}
```

}

Como posso criar esses três métodos Get? Estou fazendo da forma correta com o Get com filtros para padrão REST?
Ps.: Meus POST fiz no padrão, tudo em JSON, mas no GET não soube como solucionar a fitragem.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara, você já tem 2 Get's e gostaria de fazer mais um?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, ve se ficou melhor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, mas o seu `GET` com os parâmetros opcionais pode ser dessa forma:

```
[HttpGet,Route("api/Pessoas/ListarFiltrados")]
public IHttpActionResult ListarFiltrados(string? Nome= null, string? Sobrenome= null, int? idade= null)  
{
    var pessoas = db.Pessoas(Nome, Sobrenome, idade);
    return Ok(pessoas );
}
```

Repare que na frente de cada tipo tem o sinal de `?` que permite com que os atributos passados possam ser nulos.

A URL ficaria dessa forma:

```
../api/ListarFiltrados?Nome=Diego&Sobrenome=Augusto&idade=23
```

Uma outra opção seria utilizar [ParameterBinding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) onde você pode passar um objeto inteiro para seu `Endpoint`:

```
public IHttpActionResult ListarFiltrados([FromUri]Pessoa pessoa) {...}
```

Model Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome{ get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome{ get; set; }
    public int? Idade{ get; set; }
}
```

A `queryString` permanece a mesma.

Comment: É quase isso que preciso, como vou ter diversas propriedades que posso enviar filtros, tem como eu receber tudo em uma única string e assim montar dinamicamente?
Com o código abaixo por exemplo consigo criar um array da queryString e aí sim  tentar algo dinamicamente, mas não consigo bater na action correta, segue código:  
    `string[] filtros = Request.RequestUri.Query.Substring(1).Split('&');`

Comment: Se você tiver tudo isso em um Objeto você pode usar `parameter binding`, vou adicionar um exemplo na pergunta

Comment: No objeto `Request.RequestUri.Query`vem exatamente o queryString mas vem na action errada

Comment: @JoãoPaulo desconhecia essa forma q vc estava utilizando, editei a resposta veja se pode te ajudar com algo.

Comment: Foi uma forma que encontrei não sei nem se é melhor ou nem se é correta, agora vi que é mais complicado, ve se tem alguma idéia:
Tenho uma modal no front-end com uma lista, em cada coluna o usuário pode preencher um filtro que seria um "contendo" em cada coluna, essa foi a forma que vi para receber os dados dos filtros, por querystring, se tiver outra forma...
Outra dificuldade é montar o `Where` do EF dinamicamente, porque normalmente faria:
`.Where(a => a.Nome.Contains("a") &&  a.Endereco.Contains("ponte")`
Mas pode ou não virem essas props e podem ser outras